# How to switch a value to negative based on cell value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to write a code to change a positive value into a negative value based on a cell value.

Basically, I want to copy/paste data with room charges from a reservation site, and automatically switch the charges to negative values if the value in an adjacent cell is "Cash Out" or "Card Refund"

May I have some help?

The price column is protected so my staff cannot change the prices by hand. So we cannot edit directly the room charges

```js
function refund() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange('$P1')

  if(sheet.getRange("$Q1").getValue("Cash Out" || "Card Refund"))
  { 
    cell.setValue(*-1);
  }
}
```

But I get an error. I'm totally green in coding I don't really know what I'm doing... I just copy/paste the existing code and tried to make it works without success so far -_-

Answer (score 0):

It might be the condition. You can not get one value OR another, you need to compere the two values. Thy changing to:

```
if(sheet.getRange("$Q1").getValue("Cash Out") || sheet.getRange("$Q1").getValue("Card Refund"))
```

Comment: Hey Thank you very much it seems to work but now I have a different error.

Cannot find method getValue(string). (line 5, file "Code")